# How to check in a listView if spinners are used. Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, android-viewholder

I'm working on an android app. I have found how to put dynamically a Spinner in each row.
I need that every spinner must be used before the list will be sent to a DB with a click on a button.
My problem is with spinners how to check if every spinner was used? Is there a library or something else?

My code:
The spinner's name is "viewHolder.spin

```
 class ViewHolder{
            protected TextView text;
            protected Spinner spin;
            public TextView coeffTV;

        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View view = null;
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null){

                view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowview, null);
                final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
                viewHolder.spin = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spin_sous_rubrique);
                viewHolder.coeffTV = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.coeffTV);
                final String[] items = {" ","juste","faux"};
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                viewHolder.spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: You want to add spinner into listview

Comment: I want to check if users have made a choice in the spinner.

Comment: Means you need spinner selected value of every row ...

Comment: at the end I need values of every Spinner but at first I just need to know if users made a choice in every Spinner.

Comment: Means you need how to pass multiple values of each spinner to adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each spinner should implement an OnItemSelectedListener that provides 2 methods, onItemSelected and onNothingSelected. You can make a boolean for each spinner or have a list to contain all the booleans. Then in the onItemSelected method, you can set the boolean to true if it an item was selected.

```
//List of booleans
boolean[] spinnersClicked= new boolean[numberOfSpinners-1];

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View view, int pos, long id) {
    //Item was clicked, set boolean to true
    spinnersClicked[i]=true;
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
  // Do nothing.
}
```

}

Now when someone clicks on your submit to database button, you can loop through your array of booleans and see if they are all used.

```
public boolean allSpinnersTrue(boolean[]bools)
    {
        for(boolean spinnerClicked:bools)
        {
            if(!spinnerClicked)
                //At least one spinner isn't in use
                return false;
        }
        //All spinners are used
        return true;
    }
```